# QGIS Vector Grid tool differences in Apple and Windows?

Tags: qgis, windows, grids-graticules, apple

Seeing a different Vector Grid tool in Apple and Windows OS. Apple is using 2.14.8 and Windows is using 2.16.3 
Is this due to different versions of QGIS or is it an OS issue?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On windows 2.14 you get the same layout as the one you see on your Apple. The one you see in 2.16 is the form from the tool in the Processing toolbox.

So it isn't an apple/windows thing; just different versions of QGIS.

Comment: Good to know, thank you for the answer. What is the best way to find QGIS tool layouts past and present ?

Comment: Install the various versions of the software...

Comment: No issues installing multiple versions of QGIS at the same time? Would be helpful if there was a QGIS tools archives showing the evolution of all the layouts.